# How to call method from model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model, call

I'm trying to call a method from my model with:

```
<p>
<strong>Holidays this year:</strong>
<%= Country.all_holidays_in(2014) %>
</p>
```

I have also tried putting my methods in my Controller, but it won't work.
But I just get this Error:

```
NoMethodError in Countries#show

Showing C:/xampp/htdocs/fluxcapacitor/app/views/countries/show.html.erb where line #15 raised:

undefined method `all_holidays_in' for Country(id: integer, name: string, countrycode: string):Class
```

Here's my model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

  validates :name, presence: true 
  validates :countrycode, presence: true

  def all_holidays_in(y)                                
    from = Date.civil(y,1,1)                                                            
    to = Date.civil(y,12,31)                                                            
    return Holidays.between(from, to, self.countrycode)                                     
   end
end
```

Any Ideas how I can call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def self.all_holidays_in(y)                              #
    from = Date.civil(y,1,1)                                                            #
    to = Date.civil(y,12,31)                                                            #
    return Holidays.between(from, to, self.countrycode)                                     
end
```

You need to make it a class method by doing self.method_name

In fact that won't work, hadn't noticed the country code.  Leave the method as it is but you need an instance of the country to call it.

So if in you controller you have

```
@country = Country.first
```

You can then do

```
@country.all_holidays_in(2014)
```

With your current method.

Comment: you don't need the explicit `return`

Comment: Realise that, but I copied and pasted to show the class method.  It doesn't hurt anything and maybe OP added that in to make it explicitly clear what is returned.